# New machine/OS visual artifacting and powering off, what's the cause?

Tags: nvidia, display, laptop, asus

Update: Returned the machine, bought a different one.

Background: On an ASUS Rog Zephyrus G14 (ga402xv-g14.r94060), Windows 11 was powering off randomly.  This particularly occurred during the installation of Armoury Crate perhaps due to one of the screen dimming softwares.  I was worried that the BIOS was damaged, so I flashed it with the EZ Flash directions from their website. The issues continued so I tried the BIOS tests which all passed.  The powering off issue and bad gesture animation support (not 1 to 1) motivated a move away from Windows.  There were 4 more OS attempts: Debian, Arch + bttrfs + timeshift + [asus-linux kernel headers](https://asus-linux.org/wiki/), Mint, Ubuntu.  Debian powered itself off 5x during the installation, Ubuntu did twice.  They all had boot and display issues.

Background: Debian, after installation, would crash and reboot after getting 1.7s into the boot sequence, init=/bin/bash did not help nor did blacklisting the nouveau drivers.  Arch was fine in Wayland until installing the Nvidia drivers at which point it only X11 worked.  I got the gestures working again with touchegg + x11gesures (gnome extension).  Unfortunately, the animation when switching desktops was a bit glitchy.  There were after images that looked like pixelated pink grids randomly arranged in blocks which sometimes seemed to correlate to the background image or underlying windows.  These glitches and a failure to resume from sleep were deal breakers.  Immediately after getting into Linux Mint 21.2 "Victoria", the screen brightness controls didn't work.  After using the builtin driver installation utility to install the nvidia 535 driver, the gdm login wouldn't start, but the other tty was fine so I mucked around for a tad before I jumped ship yet again.

During the installation of **Ubuntu 23.10.1** from a 128GB-Samsung LiveUSB (created with Ubuntu 20.04.6's Startup Disk Creator), there's a dotted grid pattern along the corner of the installation window [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHqZj.png). Terminal is in the background running auto-cpufreq to possibly prevent overheating.  I used the Expanded installation option with the 3rd party software and media formats boxes checked.  After installation into Ubuntu, things have been mostly cozy, the biggest issue occurred when trying to change the screen resolution or refresh rate [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzVEj.png).  This continues to happen for all of the settings tested aside from the native resolution.  Occasionally there's some ghosting in the borders of the windows (possibly an issue with drop shadows).  Sometimes the mouse freezes too.  I want 1 to 1 workspace switching gestures with kinetic scrolling and fractional scaling. I'm just missing kinetic scrolling.

This inability to hibernate makes for a pretty terrible experience.  The machine powered off while running the blender benchmark on battery and watching the power usage statistics with the gnome watt meter extension (~80W).  The machine powered off again just after installing vitals with watt meter active.

Question: When I wait on battery for hibernate and close the lid, the screen doesn't turn on, the keyboard backlight does.  I can't dim the keyboard, brighten the screen, or go to another tty.  How do I fix this?  I've got serious concerns for stability.  How can I diagnose and fix this?

Here are some blender benchmark results from the current Ubuntu configuration.

1. RTX4060 - 3833 : (3.4) https://opendata.blender.org/benchmarks/1ce11d7f-dbb5-4774-90da-2315c9fe33a9/
2. 7940HS - 245 : (4.0) https://opendata.blender.org/benchmarks/2e461272-a705-4f19-8f25-a72dabc27c3a/
3. RTX4060 - 3544 : (4.0) https://opendata.blender.org/benchmarks/ba625b4a-c942-4f2f-a370-ba8642ff490d/

[image]
[image]